# How do i fetch data inside a controller using laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm

I just started learning laravel.

I don't know how can I fetch data inside a controller,
I want to use that data inside a controller to make more rules.

```
  //Get Data From Database
    $db = DonorDetail::where('donation_id', $paytmResponse['ORDERID'])->get();

    $name     = $db['donor_name'];
    $email_id = $db['email_id'];
```

**DonorDetail** is my model to connect to my database.

I tried this code, but getting undefined error.

I'm trying to select only 1 row using the unique `donation_id` and use data of other columns of data inside my controller.

Comment: what exact error are you seeing?

Comment: Undefined index: donor_name

Comment: `get` would return a collection, not a single model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get` returns a collection. You should use `first` to get the first result from your query:

```php
DonorDetail::where('donation_id', $paytmResponse['ORDERID'])->first();
```

If no results were found, `null` will be returned, so you should also pay attention to that.

You only provided us with a small portion of your code, but it seems like you're doing a lot of things in a non-Laravel way. It's only natural because, as you mentioned, you're just starting with Laravel. My recommendation to you is to check out Laracast's free "Laravel From Scratch" course:
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch

It's by far the best resource for developers taking their first steps in Laravel (and it also has good resources for experienced developers).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use dd() to see the data.

```
dd($db);
```

However, If you want to fetch only first matching data, use following

```
$db = DonorDetail::where('donation_id', $paytmResponse['ORDERID'])->first();
$name     = $db->donor_name;
$email_id = $db->email_id;
```